# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token C - JQUERY - Passing and Decoding Json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have met with this error telling me that there is an unexpected token C pointing to my Jquery file. After much research, i am under assuming that the reason why i am getting this error is because the Json value passed back is already decoded and thus decoding it again will result in this error.

Is this statement true ? or is there another reason behind ?
This is my what my json data looks like **[{"comments":"Greta"},{"comments":"John"}]**

```
<a onclick="showUser('.$row['ID'].')" >Show Comments</a>

<script>
function showUser(str) {
      if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
      } 
      $.ajax({
          type:'post',
          url: 'viewCommentsJson.php',
          data:{q:str},
          success:function(data)
          {
              data = $.parseJSON(data);
              var response;
              $.each(data, function(index, value){
                   response += value+'<br />';
              });
              $('#txtHint').html(response);
          }
      });
}
</script>
```

Comment: _Json value passed back is already decoded and thus decoding it again will result in this error._ __Yes its true__ See console error http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/j65Ce/

Comment: From the jQuery docs about [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) (in reference to the `dataType` parameter: _"The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string). "_...

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that, you are trying to parse the response which is already in json format.

`$.parseJSON` method should apply in `string` type. Since your server response is `json`, you dont have to parse it again.

Change your code like this,

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'viewCommentsJson.php',
    data: {
        q: str
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var response = "";
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            response += value.comments + '<br />';
        });
        $('#txtHint').html(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: so are you suggestion that i remove` data = $.parseJSON(data); `completely and leave the rest as per normal ?

Comment: By doing that i will get this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '74' in Connected to MySQL<br>[{"comments":"ashdhasasbsd"},{"comments":"sdds"}]`

Comment: there isnt a specific line. It is pointing to my `jquery-1.9.0.js:945`

Comment: Can you alert that data in succes. And see what is voming from server

Answer (score 1):

This is presumable because the response is 'Connection failed ...' and you are trying to parse the database output to JSON, when the connection was refused.

This would cause the C to be parsed and would throw an "Unexpected token C" error.

Check your 'network' tab in your inspector and look for the .PHP SQL script. At least in the chrome inspector you can get the response and see when kind of response you are getting.